# Transferring a Clash Royale account with the removal of Game Center

Tags: data-transfer, games, game-center

So I heard that recently Apple has decided to remove the standalone app for game center and replace it with all this gimmicky stuff. I was wondering how am I supposed to transfer my clash royale account to a new device without game center?

Answer (score 2):

You can still login into Game Center inside the Settings. On a new device you login into Game Center with the same Apple ID as your old device and your done.

[image: Settings > Game Center option]

So all the synchronization of high scores, progress and achievements still works. Apple decided to focus on the background technology for Game developers instead of the stand alone app.